# subscript appearing properly but following character are italic

Tags: math-mode, errors

To write subscript say, x subscript 1 , I am writing x_1. However, the problem is that anything following 1 appears to be italic.

Why is it so? I am using Kile as editor.

Comment: don't ignore errors from TeX, if you get an error the typeset output is not intended to be sensible TeX just recovers enough to check for more errors. `_` only works in math mode so you need `$x_1$` At the `_` tex gave an error and inserted a `$` to enter math mode, but never leaves it until it reaches something not allowed in math mode, when it would give another error.

Comment: This is unrelated to [tag:latex3]

Comment: Please, have you read _any_ LaTeX learning manual? I know it sounds strange, but such books are useful to avoid basic errors like this one. There is a good list of them: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11

Comment: I did not get such error, please provide MWE.

Comment: I got this error and it was resolved by placing '$' on both sides of x_1 Fr example, to write x subscript i, I have to write $x_1$